# malformed UTF-8 character when calling rindex() on string containing trademark symbol

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, utf-8

I’m having a hard time figuring out why rindex() is raising an exception on the trademark character in my Rails3.0.7 app (ruby 1.8.7):

```
irb(main):007:0> "™ foo™".mb_chars.rindex(/\W/)
ActiveSupport::Multibyte::EncodingError: malformed UTF-8 character
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:72:in `u_unpack'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/multibyte/chars.rb:167:in `rindex'
from (irb):7
irb(main):008:0> "™ foo™".mb_chars.index(/\W/)
=> 1
```

But this works fine.

```
irb(main):009:0> "® foo®".mb_chars.rindex(/\W/)
=> 1
irb(main):010:0> "® foo®".mb_chars.index(/\W/)
=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your source code encoding could be the cause. Check to see exactly what this string contains at runtime. This may help you http://ruby-unicode.rubyforge.org/doc/

Comment: `irb(main):009:0> "™ foo™".each_char {|c| puts "#{c.ord}:#{c}"}`
`226:™`
`32: `
`102:f`
`111:o`
`111:o`
`226:™`
`=> "™ foo™"`
`irb(main):010:0> "™ foo™".is_utf8?`
`=> true`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't format nicely. The console snippet shows that the string is UTF8. The same result happens if mb_chars() is called on the string beforehand. It appears that rindex() has trouble with \226 when it's the last character in a UTF8 string and you call rindex() on it with the Regexp I use above.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in ActiveSupport.

Here's how to replicate it reliably, without resorting to pasting characters (which is often unreliable).

The relevant codepoints are:

```
TM symbol = 0x2122
registered symbol = 0xAE
```

Code:

```
$KCODE = 'u'
tm_char = [0x2122].pack('U')
r_char = [0xAE].pack('U')
tm_char.mb_chars.rindex(/\W/)  # error: malformed utf-8
r_char.mb_chars.rindex(/\W/)  # ok, but I expected 0 instead of nil
tm_char.mb_chars.rindex(tm_char)  # ok. but we're not using a regexp
```

I suspect it has to do with TM being a 3-byte UTF-8 char, while "(R)" is a 2-byte:

```
tm_char.bytes.to_a.inspect
r_char.bytes.to_a.inspect
```

The same thing happens with mdash (0x2014).

Ruby 1.9.2 doesn't have this issue:

```
[0x2122].pack('U').mb_chars.rindex(/\W/)  # => 0
[0x2014].pack('U').mb_chars.rindex(/\W/)  # => 0
```

Here's an ugly workaround to find the last non-word character along with its index. It even works correctly rather than ignoring the multibyte symbols.

```
mb_string = "#{tm_char} foo#{tm_char}".mb_chars
match, rev_idx = mb_string.chars.to_a.reverse.each_with_index.detect{|e,idx| e =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ }
idx = mb_string.size - rev_idx - 1  # => 5
```